# Get Substrings from binary string with equal no. of 1s and 0s as separated groups

Tags: c#, algorithm

I want to separate a binary number string into substrings that meet the following two conditions

1.The substring must contain an equal number of 0s and 1s.
2.The substring must group 0s and 1s separately together.

**Example 1:**

**Input:**

`1100110010`

**Output:**

`"1100", "1100", "10", "01", "01", "10", "10", "0011"`

**Example 2:**

**Input:**

`1100`

**Output:**

`"1100", "10"`

I tried several ways but failed.

**Attempt:**

```
   string binaryString = "1100110010";
    List<string> substrings = new List<string>();
    int startIndex = 0;
    int endIndex = 0;

    while (endIndex < binaryString.Length)
    {
        int zeros = 0;
        int ones = 0;
        endIndex = startIndex;

        while (endIndex < binaryString.Length && ((zeros == 0 && ones == 0) || (binaryString[endIndex] == binaryString[endIndex - 1])))
        {
            if (binaryString[endIndex] == '0')
            {
                zeros++;
            }
            else
            {
                ones++;
            }
            endIndex++;
        }

        if (zeros == ones)
        {
            substrings.Add(binaryString.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex));
        }

        startIndex = endIndex;
    }

    foreach (string substring in substrings)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(substring);
    }
```

Plz help me to solve this!

Comment: maybe a recursive approach would benefit you.  You can try to map out an algorithm which will go down all the way where you have 2 digits left. return the pairs and the accumulated/combined strings which complies with the the conditions

Comment: `I tried several ways but failed.` How does it failed?

Comment: This giving me 1001 output

Comment: I also think a recursive approach that checks if the substring has equal number of zeros and ones and adds them to a list could work

Comment: @Thanushka What are the inputs and it's expected outputs? Can there be overlapping substrings in the output?

Comment: There are three `'10'` groups - did you missed one accidentally?

Comment: Ah yes 3 10 i missed 1 thanks you

Comment: @nice_dev  for input 1100110010 output should be "1100", "1100", "10", "01", "01", "10", "10"

for input 1100 output should be "1100", "10"

Comment: @Thanushka Since you want all substrings in the output that follow this rule, simply check for every substring and add them to the result.

Comment: What should be the result of the string `11010`

Comment: why isn't `0011` included in your first expected output? If I understand you correctly, it should be included twice

Comment: @Charlieface for input 11010 output should be 10, 10

Comment: @derpirscher I'm very sorry i missed that also thank you!

Comment: @Thanushka why doesn't the output of `11010` not include `01`?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you're looking for all substrings of the form `1^n0^n` or `0^n1^n`. Suggested algorithm: (1) Look for every occurrence of `10` and `01`; (2) For every occurrence of `10`, yield `10, 1100, 111000, etc.,` up to the maximum possible; (3) Likewise for `01` with `01, 0011, 000111, etc.`.

Comment: Another possibility is to get all substrings of your string, which only consist of the same character (ie split 1100110 into 11, 00 , 11, 0). Then you can look at two contious items in that list and generate all substrings up to the possible length ...

Comment: The problem with your code is the instruction "startIndex = endIndex;" at the end of the loop that should rather be "startindex++".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an algorithm that works based on your conditions and test cases:

```
    string entry = "1100110010";

    for (int i = 0; i < entry.Length; i++)
        for (int j = i; j < entry.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            string newSub = entry.Substring(i, entry.Length-j);        
            if (newSub.Length % 2 == 0 && newSub.Length>=2)
            {
                string subLeft = newSub.Substring(0,newSub.Length/2);
                string subRight = newSub.Substring(newSub.Length / 2, newSub.Length / 2);
                int leftSum = subLeft.Sum(x => x - '0');
                int rightSum = subRight.Sum(x => x - '0');
                if ((leftSum == subLeft.Length && rightSum ==0) ||
                   (rightSum == subRight.Length && leftSum == 0))
                    Console.WriteLine(newSub);
            }
        }
```

Explanation:
The `Fors` are helping to obtain all the combinations by decomposing the given string char by char. Then we test each substring if its length is even because all the pairs that we are looking for should be even. Next we split into 2 equal parts the previous substring and we try to add the numbers from each part. If the added sum is the same as the length of the summing part (ex 111 -> 3 because they should be grouped) or the sum is 0 ( ex 000 -> 0) than this is the substring that we are looking for.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please explain your approach ...

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach where you iterate through the source string index by index. For each index, [System.Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=net-7.0) methods are used to investigate the current and the necessary following index values to verify whether a valid substring *starts* at the given index.

The thought behind this approach is that (given the rules you have set) **maximum *one* substring can be created when starting at any given index in the source string**. Hence, for each index in the source string, we only need to look for a single substring that complies with the rules. Either we find it, or we don't.

For each index `i` (except for the last one, because according to the rules, no substring can be one character long), it goes as follows:

1. Find out how many chars in a row are equal to the char at index `i`, starting at index `i`
2. The single possible substring that can be created when starting at index `i` will be twice as long as the char count found in the previous step; calculate it (nice to have, as it will be used twice later)
3. If we see that our potential substring will reach an index that is out of scope, there is no reason to check whether it exists; continue to the next index
4. Get the remaining chars that will complete the potential substring
5. Check whether all of those chars are equal. If they are *not* all equal, we do not have a substring that complies with the rules. Continue to the next index
6. If we have reached this far, the substring is valid

---

As an example, if we have your substring

```
"1100110010"
```

and we look at index `6`:

```
"1100110010"
       ^
```

the step-by-step evaluations will be:

1. The char at index `6` is `0`. Starting at index `6`, we find two consecutive `0`s. Hence, the char count is `2`.

```
"1100110010"
       ^^
```

2. Based on our findings in the first step, we know that the only possible *valid* substring that may exist when starting at index `6` is twice as many characters long: `2 * 2 = 4`.
3. When starting at index `6` and counting `4` characters, we are still 'inside' our source string --> all is good!

```
"1100110010"
       ^^^^
```

4. The remaining chars (i.e. two chars, starting at index `6 + 2 = 8` that constitute the substring we will be examining are `10`.

```
"1100110010"
         ^^
```

5. In `10`, all of the chars are *not* equal. Hence, the substring we are examining is *not* valid. We will skip step 6 and go to index `7`.

---

A possible implementation for this approach could be (wrapped inside a method):

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetSubstringsFrom(string source)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < source.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        var equalDigitCount = source
            .Skip(i)
            .TakeWhile(letter => letter == source[i])
            .Count();
        
        var totalDigitCount = 2 * equalDigitCount;
        
        if (i + totalDigitCount > source.Length)
        {
            continue;
        }
        
        var remainingDigits = source
            .Skip(i + equalDigitCount)
            .Take(equalDigitCount);
        
        if (remainingDigits.Distinct().Count() > 1)
        {
            continue;
        }
        
        yield return source.Substring(i, totalDigitCount);
    }
}
```

So, if you have your source string and call the method:

```
var binaryString = "1100110010";

var result = GetSubstringsFrom(binaryString);
```

the following substring will be detected for each index:

> [i = 0]   **1 1 0 0** 1 1 0 0 1 0
> [i = 1]   1 **1 0** 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
> [i = 2]   1 1 **0 0 1 1** 0 0 1 0
> [i = 3]   1 1 0 **0 1** 1 0 0 1 0
> [i = 4]   1 1 0 0 **1 1 0 0** 1 0
> [i = 5]   1 1 0 0 1 **1 0** 0 1 0
> [i = 6]   1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0   <-- No valid substring here
> [i = 7]   1 1 0 0 1 1 0 **0 1** 0
> [i = 8]   1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 **1 0**
> [i = 9]   (not evaluated)

Hence, the resulting substrings are:

```
{ "1100", "10", "0011", "01", "1100", "10", "01", "10" }
```

Example fiddle is found [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V8Qly8).

Comment: I like your approach, but "is looped only once" is not quite right. Linq is doing all other hidden loops.

Comment: @DA You are absolutely right; I appreciate your feedback. Will rephrase my answer!

Answer (score 1):

- Since you need actual substrings, there is no escape from a quadratic approach.
- So check for every substring, but *do an early exit* if the substring follows the pattern of `1...0..1` or `0...1..0` as these aren't the strings where the 1s and 0s are grouped together.
- For every substring, get the count of zeroes and ones and take the minimum among them. The minimum among them will be the count of both `0`s and `1`s individually.

There is an additional catch. When you get the minimum from count of both, make sure  your substring starts with the character that has the minimum count to get the exact  valid substring.

**Snippet:**

```
private static List<string> solve(string s){
  List<string> ans = new List<string>();
  for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i){
    int zeroes = 0, ones = 0;
    for(int j = i; j < s.Length; ++j){
        if(ones > 0 && zeroes > 0) break;
        int k = j;
        while( k < s.Length && s[k] == s[j]){
          if(s[j] == '0') zeroes++;
          else ones++;
          k++;
        }
        j = k - 1;
    }
    int equals = Math.Min(zeroes, ones);
    if(equals > 0 && (zeroes == equals && s[i] == '0' || ones == equals && s[i] == '1')) ans.Add(s.Substring(i, equals << 1));
  }
  return ans;
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/csharp/3z3v9wp9f)

Comment: *"Since you need actual substrings, there is no escape from a quadratic approach."* I kind of disagree. The substrings of interest have to be centered on `10` and `01`, which act as separators, and so the number of substrings in the result is guaranteed to be linear. And they can be enumerated in linear time. Of course, if you want to print them, then the total number of characters printed will be quadratic, but if you only want to print them as pairs of indices (start, end), then it can be done in linear time relatively easily.

Comment: @Stef I actually meant the same as you said but worded it differently. Yes, if it were only for the indices, the whole approach can be tweaked.